# Retrieve RadGrid cell value in ItemDataBound - "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid, itemdatabound

I am trying to set a CssClass based on a the comparison of two cell values in my radGrid.  Both cells are formatted for currency `{0:c}`, so that when I compare them, I have a $ sign in the text string.  I know how to parse a string to remove the $ sign, which is what I am doing.  However, is there a way to get the raw text of the cell prior to formatting, so that I will not have this error?

Here is my code:

ASPX:

```
                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgCISPartsInfo" DataSourceID="dsCISItem" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        GridLines="None" AllowPaging="False" OnItemDataBound="rgCISPartsInfo_ItemDataBound" runat="server" Width="676px">
                        <MasterTableView AllowPaging="False" DataKeyNames="SalesOrderItemId">
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="COST" DataField="AverageCostPrice" AllowSorting="false"
                                    DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right"
                                    HeaderStyle-Width="80px">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtendedCost" HeaderText="X COST" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" 
                                HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Weight" HeaderText="WT" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" 
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </MasterTableView>
                    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

C#:

```
protected void rgCISPartsInfo_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // only access item if not header or footer cell
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            GridColumn column = rgCISPartsInfo.MasterTableView.GetColumn("AverageCostPrice");

            decimal cost = Convert.ToDecimal(dataItem["AverageCostPrice"].Text);
            decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(dataItem["Price"].Text);
            if (cost > price)
            {
                dataItem.CssClass = "Grid_Red_Row";
                throw new Exception("Item Cost is greater than price.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GlobalHelper.ShowErrorMessage(this.Page.Master, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
The selected solution is the answer to my question, but I ultimately decided to simply parse the string for the $ sign, as it was the simplest solution.

Comment: BTW, here's how to modify the formatting from code-behind: `GridColumn column = rgCISPartsInfo.MasterTableView.GetColumn("AverageCostPrice");   ((GridBoundColumn)column).DataFormatString = "{0:c}";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add RadGridDataBound filed with `visible="fasle"` and different unique name and access it from the code behind.

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgCISPartsInfo" DataSourceID="dsCISItem" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        GridLines="None" AllowPaging="False" OnItemDataBound="rgCISPartsInfo_ItemDataBound" runat="server" Width="676px">
                        <MasterTableView AllowPaging="False" DataKeyNames="SalesOrderItemId">
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="COST" DataField="AverageCostPrice" AllowSorting="false"
                                    DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right"
                                    HeaderStyle-Width="80px">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                       <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="COST" DataField="AverageCostPrice" Visiable="false" uniqueName="AverageCostPrice1"  DataField="AverageCostPrice" >
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ExtendedCost" HeaderText="X COST" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" 
                                HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Weight" HeaderText="WT" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" 
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </MasterTableView>
                    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

C#

```
  decimal cost = Convert.ToDecimal(dataItem["AverageCostPrice1"].Text);
```

**PS:**
Another idea I just had is to assign the `DataFormatString` durring the `ItemDataBound` event. this way you'll have the raw string.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not use format string in the markup and do it in the ItemDataBound event instead.

Comment: I am not able to get this to work, as ItemDataBound is executed for every row in the grid.  After setting DataFormatString for one item, the error will occur again for the next item.  I also tried using the radGrid PreRender method, to no avail.